# make select product and product price not mandatory

Tags: node.js

I have to make the product and product price non mandotory. I am new to node js can please somebody can help me

```
const addServiceSchema = Joi.object().keys({
name: Joi.required(),
price: Joi.number().required(),
categoriesId: Joi.required(),
serviceImg: Joi.required(),
description: Joi.required(),
productsId: Joi.required(),
productPriceOnUsage: Joi.required(),
serviceTotalPrice: Joi.required(),
serviceTime: Joi.required(),
salonsId: Joi.required(),
method: Joi.required()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `.required()` with `Joi.string().allow('', null)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.required()` from the properties that are not required.
The Joi `required()` is a validation that tells the joi schema you defined that the property price, for example, must not be empty.